# Will stringstream become infinite large?

Tags: c++, stringstream

https://ideone.com/c7DTEv

If I continue to add string to `stringstream` and read from it, will does the size of `stringstream` become infinite large?

Because i need `stringstream` as a member variable to let every member function to access it.

Or there any way to delete data that already read in `stringstream`?

Comment: stringstream is C++, so I've retagged.

Comment: Adding to the stringstream will increase the allocated size accordingly, but extracting from the stream does not appear to provide a corresponding reduction. [std::basic_stringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) makes no mention of a deallocation on extraction either. Would a `std::vector<std::string>` object work where you could index an individual string needed or pop or erase when done with an individual string work?